# Why Requests library cannot read the source-code?

Tags: python, python-requests

I've been writing a python script for all the Natas challenges. So far, everything went smooth.

In challenge natas22, there is nothing on the page, but it gives you the link of the source-code. From the browser, I can reach to the source-code (which is PHP) and read it. But I cannot do it with my Python script. Which is very weird, because I've done that in other challenges...

I also tried to give a user-agent (up to date chrome browser), did not work.

Here is the small code:

```
import requests

user = 'natas22'
passw = 'chG9fbe1Tq2eWVMgjYYD1MsfIvN461kJ'
url = 'http://%s.natas.labs.overthewire.org/' % user

response = requests.get('http://natas22.natas.labs.overthewire.org/index-source.html', auth=(user, passw))
print(response.text)
```

Which returns:

```
<code><span style="color: #000000">
<br /></span>ml&gt;id="viewsource"&gt;&lt;a&nbsp;href="index-source.html"&gt;View&nbsp;sourcecode&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;nbsp;next&nbsp;level&nbsp;are:&lt;br&gt;";l.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
</code>
```

But in fact, it should had returned:

```
<?  session_start(); 

if(array_key_exists("revelio", $_GET)) { 
    // only admins can reveal the password 
    if(!($_SESSION and array_key_exists("admin", $_SESSION) and $_SESSION["admin"] == 1)) { 
    header("Location: /"); 
    }  }  ?> 


<html>  <head>  <!-- This stuff in the header has nothing to do with the level -->  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://natas.labs.overthewire.org/css/level.css">  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://natas.labs.overthewire.org/css/jquery-ui.css" />  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://natas.labs.overthewire.org/css/wechall.css" />  <script src="http://natas.labs.overthewire.org/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  <script src="http://natas.labs.overthewire.org/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>  <script src=http://natas.labs.overthewire.org/js/wechall-data.js></script><script src="http://natas.labs.overthewire.org/js/wechall.js"></script>  <script>var wechallinfo = { "level": "natas22", "pass": "<censored>" };</script></head>  <body>  <h1>natas22</h1>  <div id="content"> 

<? 
    if(array_key_exists("revelio", $_GET)) { 
    print "You are an admin. The credentials for the next level are:<br>"; 
    print "<pre>Username: natas23\n"; 
    print "Password: <censored></pre>"; 
    }  ?> 

<div id="viewsource"><a href="index-source.html">View sourcecode</a></div>  </div>  </body>  </html>
```

Why it's behaving like this? I'm very curious and couldn't find out

If you want the url for trying from the browser:

> url: http://natas22.natas.labs.overthewire.org/index-source.html
>
> Username: natas22
>
> Password: chG9fbe1Tq2eWVMgjYYD1MsfIvN461kJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import requests

user = 'natas22'
passw = 'chG9fbe1Tq2eWVMgjYYD1MsfIvN461kJ'
url = 'http://%s.natas.labs.overthewire.org/' % user

response = requests.get('http://natas22.natas.labs.overthewire.org/index-source.html', auth=(user, passw))
print(response.text.replace('\r', '\n'))
```

This also works:

```
import requests

user = 'natas22'
passw = 'chG9fbe1Tq2eWVMgjYYD1MsfIvN461kJ'
url = 'http://%s.natas.labs.overthewire.org/' % user

response = requests.get('http://natas22.natas.labs.overthewire.org/index-source.html', auth=(user, passw))
print(response.content.decode('utf8').replace('\r', '\n'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be fine. The source code use `\r` instead of `\n`, so most of the code is hidden in a terminal.

You can see this using `response.content` instead of `response.test` to see this:

```
import requests

user = 'natas22'
passw = 'chG9fbe1Tq2eWVMgjYYD1MsfIvN461kJ'
url = 'http://%s.natas.labs.overthewire.org/' % user

response = requests.get('http://natas22.natas.labs.overthewire.org/index-source.html', auth=(user, passw))
print(response.content)
```

Comment: and with an `import html` - then maybe `print(html.unescape(response.text.replace('\r', '\n')))` makes it more readable...